# Query that returns list of all stored procedures in a SQL Server database which have varchar as a parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there a query that returns the names of all the stored procedures in a SQL Server database that some or all his parameter has `varchar` datatype, and we can change it because we change all database table from `varchar` to `nvarchar` and there are a lot of stored procedures to change then maybe it takes a whole day so please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information_Schema has always helped me with these problems:

```
SELECT r.ROUTINE_NAME, p.PARAMETER_NAME
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS p
    ON r.SPECIFIC_CATALOG = p.SPECIFIC_CATALOG
    AND r.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = p.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA
    AND r.SPECIFIC_NAME = p.SPECIFIC_NAME
WHERE 
  p.DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
```

Comment: Can we change the datatype using any query after finding procedure and column using this query?

Comment: I believe the various parts of INFORMATION_SCHEMA are views and you therefore can't update them. You _may_ be able to manipulate the sysobjects but I'd advise against it. There's likely a lot of stuff happening behind a CREATE PROC call that would be either tedious or simply impossible to do manually. I think your best bet is to edit the stored proc code and recreate them on your DB. If you are capable, consider whipping up a simple tool to loop through your stored proc files and do some text replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Sure - try this:

```
SELECT
    ProcedureName = pr.Name,
    ParameterName = p.Name,
    TypeName = t.Name
FROM 
    sys.procedures pr
INNER JOIN 
    sys.parameters p ON p.object_id = pr.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON p.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
WHERE   
    t.Name = 'varchar'
```

You might also want to search for parameters of type `char` (which need to be converted to `nchar`) and `text` (convert to `ntext` - or better yet: `nvarchar(max)` since `text` and `ntext` are deprecated and should not be used anymore)

Comment: Can we change the datatype using any query after finding procedure and column using this query

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
      [procedure_name] = SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '.' + o.name
    , parameter_name = p.name
FROM sys.objects o WITH(NOWAIT)
JOIN sys.parameters p WITH(NOWAIT) ON p.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE TYPE_NAME(p.user_type_id) = 'varchar'
    AND o.[type] IN ('P ', 'X ', 'PC', 'RF')
```